# Conditional DateFormatter in Bokeh tables

Tags: bokeh, date-formatting, dateformatter

I can do a static choice for my date formatter in Bokeh tables

```
TableColumn(field=xdata, title=xdata, formatter=DateFormatter(format="%a, %e %b %y")),
```

but I would like to do something more dynamic, showing the time of the day if it is less than few hours away from the current time, else showing the full date (day+time)

Other questions seem to focus on cell background and stuff like that depending on conditions, so I cannot find a previously asked question that really fits for this.

Comment: There's `HTMLTemplateFormatter` that can format values using arbitrary JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

My ugly JS that does the job is the following

```
    template="""
 <%= (
         function nameless()
         { 
            function shortenDateTime(inputDate /* Date() */
                                     ,threshold /*[seconds]*/) {
              function farAway(present /* integer unit epoch */, past /* integer unit epoch */) {
                if ( present - past > threshold*1000){
                  return true;
                }   else {
                  return false;
                }
              }

              // get a new date (locale machine date time)
              var now = new Date();
              var now_epoch = now.getTime();


              inputDate_epoch = inputDate.getTime();
              date = inputDate.toDateString();
              time = inputDate.toLocaleTimeString();

              if (farAway(now_epoch,inputDate_epoch)) {
                return date + ' ' + time;
              } else {
                return time;
              }
            };
            var _date = new Date(value);
            return shortenDateTime(_date)
         }()
     ) %>;
"""
```

Then one has to define a formatter from `HTMLTemplateFormatter`

```
formater =  HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template)
```

and use it in the definition of the column

```
TableColumn(field=xdata, width=22, title=xdata, formatter=formater),
```

My only remaining issues have to do with:

- removing the `;` at the end of the output `12:09:33;`
- is it really necessary to use the trick I made with the definition of `nameless()`